# how can I check Linux kernel compiler optimisation level

Tags: linux, optimization, linux-kernel

I'm trying to verify which optimisation level (-O?) is my linux kernel built. How can I do that?

The only thing I can find is CONFIG_CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE=y in the kernel config file. Does it imply -Os? Does it override anything (having multiple optimisations in one gcc line makes the last -O the winner)? I have found some parts of the kernel built with -O2, but too few lines for all of the kernel.

Where is such optimisation centrally set?

Note: I'm using CentOS 5.5.

Comment: Why do you assume all files are built with the same optimization level?

Comment: Would be fair. Why would a file mustn't have optimisation? If it has it is faster so better for everybody.

Comment: The source is free all right, but not all distributions publish all pieces of their build infrastructure. But if you have access to it, more power to you.

Comment: The reason you can choose a different optimization or no optimization is that the optimizations may not always produce the optimal code for your particular usage scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Run with `make V=1` and you can see the command lines in all their glory.

Comment: This rests on the rather hefty assumption that you have access to the source tree, but if your vendor doesn't publish it, it's impossible, and if you only want the answer to this particular question, it's quite an ordeal to set up.

Comment: In my case I have access to the source tree. As far as I knew the Linux kernel source should be published as it is GPL, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

If your kernel config contains CONFIG_CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE you may assume it was compiled using -Os see the kernel makefile e.g. at http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.12/Makefile#L573 for the place where this get set this also shows that if CONFIG_CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE is not set that -O2 is used.

As blueshift already said, building with make V=1 forces make to display the full compiler output including optimization flags.